# Samba not authenticating

Tags: samba

Okay, so I have been going at this for over two hours and on the verge of giving up. I cannot for the life of me get Windows to authenticate with Samba. I either get "Username or Password incorrect" or "Access is Denied".

I have ran the command `sudo smbpasswd -a pi` and set a password.
I've tried adding pi to a group and forcing that group - doesn't work.

I am at a loss and, really, have no idea what I am doing.

Any help would be really appreciated as I'd rather not be doing this up until 4AM.

smb.conf:

```
[share]
    comment = usb
    path = /mnt/usb
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    public = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
```

Comment: Can you try something change the path to something in the /home/pi/ directory. Also what version of windows are you on

Comment: are your samba users also existing in your "normal" users group (they have to exist there)? I would recommend adding a user "pi2" (or something similar) to your samba and your normal user group. Another error could be the authentication from your windows machines. Maybe you have to add a path to your username if the chosen username is existing too on your windows machine.

Comment: User comment per edit: @JoshWelford: "I've tried changing the path to: /home/pi/Downloads and now the error present is An Extended error has occurred."

Comment: In your smb.conf can you find the [homes] section and make sure these 2 lines are uncommented  comment = Home Directories and browseable = yes. then you should be able to browse using network neighborhood and login via pi/raspberrry or Pi/password (that you set up for smaba) credentials, also add the workgroup as suggested by michael B below.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your `/etc/samba/smb.cnf` looks like this (unless your windows pc's domain is not workgroup):

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = raspi
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
```